# How to reach moment timestamp lines in a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a 'dateRange' Function with start Date and End Date in different formats

```
dateRangeSelected = (event, value) => {
        if (event && event.length == 2 && value === 'rangeSelected')
        {
            let statDateTime = new Date(event[0]);
            let selectedTime = moment().format('hh:mm');
            let startDate = moment(moment(statDateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + " " + selectedTime);

            this.setState({startDate : startDate });
        }
    }
```

I am writing test cases in jest. I have written these lines to reach this function

```
const components = new myComponent({ ...props });
components.dateRangeSelected(event, value);
```

I can reach the function but these moment line are shown as uncovered in coverage file. 
Any Idea how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract logic to separate function.

```js
dateRangeSelected = (event, value) => {
  if (event && event.length == 2 && value === 'rangeSelected') {
    const startDate = getStartDate(event[0]);
    this.setState({startDate});
  }
}

const getStartDate = (event) => {
  const date = moment(event);
  const currentDate = moment();
  date.set({
    hour: currentDate .hour(),
    minute: currentDate.minute()
   });
  return date;
}
```

**Example tests**

```js
const {
  core: {
    beforeEach,
    describe,
    it,
    expect,
    run
  },
} = window.jestLite;

const getStartDate = (event) => {
  const date = moment(event);
  const currentDate = moment();
  date.set({
    hour: currentDate.hour(),
    minute: currentDate.minute()
   });
  return date;
}

describe("moment", () => {
  const currentDate = new Date();

  beforeEach(() => {
      moment.now = () => currentDate;
  });
  
  it("returns hours and minutes", () => {
    const date = moment('2100-06-11 10:10:00')
    
    expect(date.hour()).toBe(10);
    expect(date.minute()).toBe(10);
  })

  it("returns date with current time", () => {    
    expect(moment(currentDate).toDate().toString()).toBe(currentDate.toString());
  })
  
  it("returns date with changed time", () => {   
    const date = moment(currentDate);
    date.set({
      hour: 10,
      minute: 10
     });
   
    expect(moment(date).format("hh:mm")).toBe("10:10");
  })
})

describe("getStartDate", () => {
  const currentDate = new Date();

  beforeEach(() => {
      moment.now = () => currentDate;
  });

  it("returns date with current time", () => {    
    const startDate = getStartDate(currentDate);
    const format = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm";
    const expectedDateFormatted = moment().format(format);

    expect(startDate.format(format)).toBe(expectedDateFormatted);
  });

});

run().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jest-lite@1.0.0-alpha.4/dist/core.js"></script>
```